# How could I save a image as a text file?

Tags: image, file-conversion

Sorry, I am not very experienced with programming and such, but I am wondering if it would be possible to convert an image to a text file. One idea I had is to look at the color of every pixel and save the HEX value of the color, then to decode it by printing out the HEX values. I don't know if this is a good way to do it, or if other ways already exist.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A text file with lots of hex values doesn't sound immediately useful on its own, what do you plan to do with it once you have it?

Comment: You can convert image to base64 and save it

Comment: There are several possibilities (some not even requiring code) but it really depends **why** you want to do that and **what** you plan to do with the result.